# Show that the analytical solution of a PDE satisfies a given Wave Equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I am only stuck on how to do the first part of the question, in the photo.

If someone can help me break-through this, I really appreciate it.[image]

Comment: Please, re-write your problem using MathJax and then show your attempts for to solve the problem.

Comment: It must be an easy attempt, as it only consists of 1 mark. So half a mark for what I am looking for. To be honest, I am trying to understand the question, as I have no idea how to show this, but if someone can just generally tell me a direction on how to go about it, and tell me what is the a,b,c,... here in this question I am happy and will do the rest myself.

Comment: where is $a,b$ and $c$? I don't understand your last part of your comment.

Comment: You are to show that any function of the form $u=f(x-t)$ satisfies the given equation. To do this, let $v=x-t$ and find $\partial^2_t u$ and $\partial^2_x u,$ then substitute in LHS of equation (2) to show that it reduces to $0$ identically.

Comment: The question is clear for me:  you have a boundary problem and you have $u(t,x)=f(x-t)$ and the question say that you need to calculate $\frac{\partial^{2}u}{\partial t^{2}}$ and $\frac{\partial^{2}u}{\partial x^{2}}$ and then you need to verify if is equation 2 is satisfied.